# Public Domain KJV Bible w/ Christ's Words in Text

Tags: reference-request

I am aware of http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Bible/King_James_Version

However, all the text there is in the same color.

I am wondering if there is a public domain (or free to share with the world) Bible where Christ's words are in Red.

Thanks!

Comment: Resource requests are not really constructive anywhere on SE.

Comment: And the KJV has rather complicated copyright status: it's still under Crown Copyright in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://christiananswers.net/bible/

also offers other versions, but meets your exact request.

Comment: Where does this website say that it's in public domain?

Comment: The KJV IS public domain, regardless of who's published a specific version. You can't copyright a work that's already public domain.  http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/King-James-Version-KJV-Bible/ version info section. And  the Christiananswers.net website is evangelical in nature. They want us to share it freely with the rest of the world.